# Sending files to remote server in the quickest manner

Tags: linux, ftp, network-protocols, socketserver

I have a separate server that processes the media uploaded to my main, web facing server. For now I upload files to it using FTP but the problem with this is that to ensure the files are done uploading I have a timeout running, which adds a delay in the overall processing time. I can't seem to get it to wait less than 5 seconds and still guarantee to pick up the media and this delay is no longer acceptable. So:

Is there a better way to implement this cleanly? I've considered sticking with FTP and sending another file after the initial upload that will indicate it's done but then there are two uploads for every upload = expensive. Another option I've considered is implementing a custom server that will just get a content-length header, do some authentication, and then receive the file and kickoff the processing as soon as its ready. Socket programming doesn't seem too intimidating but I have some worries about sending binary files and different formats, is this a valid concern? Also are there any other protocols out there I could implement to do this, rather than reinvent the wheel? Something like FTP but with a little verification.

I'd be glad for any pointers or tips you can share, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use `rsync`. This runs over `ssh`, will move entire directories / hierarchies of files, do incremental copies, in short everything you could possibly want.

Comment: but can it notify a process when files are done being sent? The issue im having here is being able to pick them up the second they come in, not before or after...

Comment: Do you mean notify something on the local server? Or notify something on the remote server? If the former, the `rsync` will complete with a success exit code, so `rsync [params] && notify-thing` will work. If the latter, just use ssh (same credentials as the `rsync`) i.e. `rsync [params] && ssh remote.server.example.com notify-thing` which will run `notify-thing` on the remote server when the `rsync` has completed successfully.

Comment: Ah, that seems like it'll work (on the remote server)